# Liquid Temperature Profile

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose I have a one meter cubed box of liquid and I know that it is in a $-4^\circ~\rm C$ room for some amount of time, but was at a uniform $25^\circ ~\rm C$ when it was placed inside.  I know I can get the average liquid temperature from Newton's law of cooling; however, I need to find an equation to create a temperature profile from the dead center of the liquid to the outside wall.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation)?